# Cookies - js file data is not updating dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am working on cookies.

**Description**:
Want to change the js file and store it in cookie.

If I click on `B2b industry` link, page should replace the js file from `banking.js` to `b2b.js` and so on...

The above scenario (replacing the js file) is working as expected.

**Problem:** 
But, after loading the script file, I am trying to replace the contents for `<h1>, <p>` tags from `b2b.js` file which is not getting effected...

Any help please?

**PS**: The same is working for CSS file switch

---

**init.js**

```
var Cookies = {
    SetCookie: function (c_name, value, exdays) {
        var exdate = new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
        var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
        document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
    },

    GetCookie: function (c_name) {
        var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
            x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
            y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
            x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
            if (x == c_name) {
                return unescape(y);
            }
        }
    }
}

// file change
if (Cookies.GetCookie("industryBased") != "") {
    setIndustryFile(Cookies.GetCookie("industryBased"));
}

function setIndustryFile(industryFileName) {
    document.getElementById("industryScriptFile").src = industryFileName;
    Cookies.SetCookie("industryBased", industryFileName, 60);
    return false;
}
```

---

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script id="industryScriptFile" src="banking.js" type="javascript"></script>
    <script src="init.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#b2b" onclick="setIndustryFile('b2b.js');return false;")>B2b industry</a></li>
      <li><a href="#travel" onclick="setIndustryFile('travel.js');return false;")>Travel industry</a></li>
      <li><a href="#healthcare" onclick="setIndustryFile('healthcare.js');return false;")>Healthcare industry</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <a href="page2.html">Go to Page 2</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**b2b.js**

```
jQuery('h1').html('B2B Industry heading...');
jQuery('p').html('B2B Industry content...');
jQuery('body').css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refers to [http://browsercookielimits.squawky.net/](http://browsercookielimits.iain.guru/)

I think your each cookies size is over-sized, so the browser not saving them.

Each browser, have different limit size for cookies storage. Make sure your cookies size is not over-sized.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that... my file size is around 120KB :(

Comment: You can use window.localStorage instead, it's API is much better and easier to use than for cookies. It should be at least 10 Mb for major browsers.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. but, there are still have limit as described from this page: http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/ So becarefull with your data size.